MVVM Framework for Razor MVC
I want to build a project using Razor MVC and want to use some MVVM framework.
I'm mostly interested in Data Binding. I would not use routing, I don't think I will be using state management, Directives, etc.
Before I worked with knockoutjs but now it is outdated.
Any suggestions?

if you are looking for a simple/small framework, i would say use knockout.js or backbone i use these frameworks when I want ajax based pages and quick simple binding at frontend, for sure if you are looking for a complete solution then react, vue, angular or some other frameworks

Does the point in this link meet your requirement?  Blazor wsam uses MVVM
